# Find the word having the maximum count using a Trident topology

Tags: apache-storm, trident, apache-storm-topology

How can I find the word which has the maximum count in a word count topology using Trident topology? Here's the link to the Trident word count topology.
https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/trident/TridentWordCount.java

Answer (score 0):

Trident API provides **max** & **maxBy** operations that return maximum value on each partition of a batch of tuples in a trident stream.

So after calculating the count of each word like below:

```
Stream wordCountsStream = topology.newStream("spout1", spout).parallelismHint(16).each(new Fields("sentence"),
        new Split(), new Fields("word")).groupBy(new Fields("word")).persistentAggregate(new MemoryMapState.Factory(),
        new Count(), new Fields("count")).parallelismHint(16).newValuesStream();
```

Use **maxBy** to get the word having the maximum count:

```
 wordCountsStream.maxBy(new Fields("count"))
```